# One-pixel error in offsetLeft (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, firefox

Assume I have a simple structure like this:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

I want to give both `#a` and `#b` fixed width and height and then center `#b` in `#a`:

```
#a { width: 199px, height: 199px; position: relative; }
#b { width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute;
     top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto }
```

The only trick here is that it cannot be centered exactly because the difference is 99px and it cannot be divided evenly, so there will be a single-pixel shift somewhere. The problem is that the screen shows me one thing, but JavaScript reports another. If I read `offsetLeft` of `#b`, I see 50px, but when I actually measure it on a screenshot, it's 49px. (`offsetTop` seems to be OK, although in the real app I also seem to get one-pixel error with it).

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe75Lp3q/).

This happens is Firefox 47.0.

Comment: the real value is 49.5, but offsetLeft returns an integer, so it rounds.

Comment: @dandavis Yes, it does (to 50px), but the actual distance on screen is 49px. I'm concerned with this discrepancy.

Comment: maybe your vga card/os/driver rounds down, the dom rounds up. perhaps other hardware would also round up. Since "retina" monitors and mobile devices use virtual pixels anyway, and cleartype and contrast settings also shift sub-pixels, you never really had per-sub-pixel control anyway, so don't worry about that which you cannot change.

Comment: can you set `left: 0.1px;` to round the same on dom and measured?

Comment: @dandavis Hmm. In fact it works. It is as if Firefox rounded horizontal 0.5 toward 0; if I nudge it even a tiny little bit, the final value rounds correctly. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.